# Logback update cause missing StaticLoggerBinder

Tags: maven, logback, slf4j

I updated logback past 1.3 and encountered this error. I found that post 1.3 logback the StaticLoggerbinder is no longer included but have no idea how to add it back in.

I have tried including various slf4j into my maven dependency which suppose to fix the issue but none of them have worked so far. I'm a at lost at how to resolve this issue.